# Facing performance issue with FB Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

When AutoLogAppEventsEnabled is enabled there is a noticeable lag when user scrolls the app content. This lag further increases as user temporarily leaves the app and comes back on the app. If this behaviour is repeated multiple times the lag further increases and leads to an unresponsive app.

However, when AutoLogAppEventsEnabled is disabled there is no lag and the scroll behaviour is smooth as expected. Also the issue with increased lag due to app paused/resumed goes away.

The issue goes away when you disable AutoLogAppEventsEnabled from AndroidManifest.xml

We ran some profiling and we noticed that when AutoLogAppEventsEnabled  is enabled there is a decent amount of work being done on the main thread of the app even if you are doing a simple action like scrolling. This is not the case when AutoLogAppEventsEnabled is disabled.

Comment: Which SDK version are you using?

Comment: Related issue on their github repo: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/618